# Postfix/LMTP rewriting username to number 1

Tags: postfix, smtp, dovecot

I have a frustrating issue with my mail server and i am confused as which part of the configuration is concerned, 
please note that both postfix and dovecot are configured to fetch configuration from mysql database. 
The mysql connection is tested with both and is working fine. 
Whenever i send an email to any of the users, here's what get logged in mail.log:

```
postfix/lmtp[6157]: A093EB0056D: to=<1@domain.com>, orig_to=<firstname.lastname@domain.com>, relay=mail.domain.com[private/dovecot-lmtp], delay=0.43, delays=0.4/0/0.01/0.01, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (host mail.domain.com[private/dovecot-lmtp] said: 550 5.1.1 <1@domain.com> User doesn't exist: 1@domain.com (in reply to RCPT TO command)
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks a lot

Ahmad

Comment: From the question it is not clear - what exactly doesn't work as it should. Could you clarify more detailed.

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for your reply. What happens is , i'm sending an email to ex: firstname.lastname@domain.com , when it gets to the server i'm seeing in the logs the log entry i posted. it changes the user to '1' ex: 1@domain.com then dovecot says 1@domain.com doesn't exist.

Comment: it seems you have some alias. Add output of the ```postfconf -n``` and ```dovecot -n``` to the question

Comment: Alex ! your reply pointed me in the right direction, apparently its an alias issue, my aliases table was empty so i disabled the alias maps (sql) from postfix main.cf and that did the trick. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Alex pointed out in his comment, the issue was indeed the aliases. 
My aliases table was empty and weirdly it was resolving to the number '1' 
so i disabled in my postfix main.cf alias maps (sql) and that did it !

Thanks to Alex !